# What is causing "Could not resolve placeholder"

Tags: java, spring, gwt

Could not resolve placeholder `'CRATL_GROUP_ID_QA'` 
 in string value `"${CRATL_GROUP_ID_QA}"`

What is causing this error ?

Comment: I'm guessing the cause of that error is that that placeholder is not there. not in any config file, not in the classpath, not anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring uses implementations of an abstract class called [`PropertySource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/PropertySource.html) which it adds to the [`Environment`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html) and from which it extracts properties. If none of the registered `PropertySource` objects contains the requested property, then the [`PropertyResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/PropertyResolver.html) trying to resolve, for example, `${CRATL_GROUP_ID_QA}`, will fail and throw the exception.